# What is the difference between using dofollow and omitting rel?

Tags: links, rel, dofollow

My main concern is whether dofollow is interpreted as more important than links without any `rel` attribute. Does it make any difference for search engines?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no such thing as "dofollow". All links are followed unless specifically stated otherwise (nofollow).

Answer (score 4):

What some people call a "dofollow" link is just a normal link - i.e. a link that does not have the `rel="nofollow"` attribute. If you use `dofollow` in the `rel` attribute of a link, it is simply ignored by search engine spiders.

So, what you want is simply something like this:

```
<a href="target.html">target</a>
```

There is no dofollow (or similar) attribute you can add to the link. The absence of `nofollow` is what you're looking for.

<sub>Note: this answer was loosely based on [this answer at Drupal Answers](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/60370).</sub>